# Login Validator Checker PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Below is my "Login Checker"
It works fine if I use the old traditional mysql connect.. but with PDO it doesnt seem to work.. mind if anyone give me a few tips or modifications to this code so that it will work?

It gives me this error:

```
Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\clubresults\checklogin.php on line 23
```

where Line 23 is $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
Thanks!!

```
<?php
ob_start();
$tbl_name="admin_passwords"; // Table name 

        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=clubresults', 'root', '12345678');
    #Set Error Mode to ERRMODE_EXCEPTION.
    $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){
// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
$_SESSION["myusername"] = "$myusername";
$_SESSION["mypassword"] = "$mypassword";
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {

echo "ACCESS DENIED.<br> Incorrect username and/or Password
<br>Please check your username and password. <br> wait five seconds for redirection. ";
}
ob_flush();
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are fully leveraging the PDOs and using the parameterized statments.

If it were me I would have written your code as follows:

```
$tbl_name="admin_passwords"; // Table name 

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=clubresults', 'root', '12345678');
#Set Error Mode to ERRMODE_EXCEPTION.
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username = :username AND password = :password");
$stmt->execute(array('username' => $_POST['myusername'], 'password' => $_POST['mypassword']));
if ($stmt->fetch() === false) {
    //access deined
    //....
}
else {
   //access granted
   //...
}
```

Also, for security purposes you should be hashing your passwords with sha1 at the least (I do sha512) in your database so that even if you data gets stolen the passwords can't be reverse engineered without quite a bit of effort.

EDIT: Looking again, it might also be good to use a user other than root to access the database, but that is more personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing the result from this line:

```
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

It looks like mysql_query might be failing because it is not being passed a link_identifier.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make pdo-query not, mysql_query.

see here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php